# Let $\phi:C^1([a,b])\to \Bbb{R}$ defined by $\phi(f)=\int\limits_a^b L(t,f(t),f'(t))\ dt$ where $L\in C^1(\Bbb{R}^3)$. Find $D\phi(f)(h)$.

Tags: calculus, integration, analysis, multivariable-calculus, banach-spaces

> Prove that $E=C^1([a,b];\Bbb{R})$ is a Banach space with respect to the norm $\lVert f\rVert=\text{sup}|f|+\text{sup}|f'|$. Let $L\in C^1(\Bbb{R}^3;\Bbb{R})$ be fixed, define $\phi:E\to \Bbb{R}$ by $$\phi(f)=\int\limits_a^b L(t,f(t),f'(t))\ dt$$ Prove that, $$D\phi(
> f)(h)=\int\limits_a^b (D_2L(t, f(t),f'(t))h(t)+D_3L(t, f(t), f'(t))h'(t))\ dt$$

I have proved the first part of the problem.

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a cauchy sequence in $E$. Let, $\epsilon>0$ then $\exists N\in\Bbb{N}$ such that $\lVert f_n-f_m\rVert <\epsilon/2\ \forall n,m\ge N$. This implies $\text{sup}|f_n-f_m|<\epsilon/2$ and $\text{sup}|f_n'-f_m'|<\epsilon/2\ \forall n,m\ge N$. This shows that $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to a function $f$ on $[a,b]$. Again, $\{f_n'\}$ also converges uniformly to a function $g$ on $[a,b]$ and it is continuous as $f_n'$ is continuous for all $n$. From the property of [derivative and uniform convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_convergence#To_differentiability) we have $f$ is differentiable and $f'=g$. Hence, $f\in E$.

Now we have $|f_n(x)-f_m(x)|<\epsilon/2$ and $|f_n'(x)-f_m'(x)|<\epsilon/2\ \forall x\in [a,b]\ \forall n,m\ge N$. Taking $m\to \infty$ we get $|f_n(x)-f(x)|\le\epsilon/2$ and $|f_n'(x)-f'(x)|\le\epsilon/2\ \forall x\in [a,b]\ \forall n\ge N\implies \text{sup}|f_n-f|+\text{sup}|f_n'-f'|\le\epsilon/2\ \forall n\ge N\implies \lVert f_n-f\rVert\le \epsilon\ \forall n\ge N$.

So, $f_n\to f$ in the NLS $(E,\lVert\cdot\rVert)$. Therefore, $E$ is a banach space.

But I have no idea how to differentiate this $\phi$. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Very interesting question. I'd imagine this comes from some question in calculus of variations / Lagrangian / maximization - minimization problem? In one-dimensional situations, I have often seen the derivative sliding under the integral. This is justified by applications of the dominated convergence theorem. Perhaps something like that can be done here.

Comment: Yes, this question is given in the chapter of Optimization.

Comment: Great! I'll have a go, along the lines I described in my previous comment. I'd imagine one can push it through to completion.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

By definition of the (Fréchet) derivative, it is sufficient to prove that

$$\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{\vert \phi(f+h) - \phi(h) - D \phi(f)(h) \vert}{\Vert h \Vert} = 0.$$

Then, you have to use the following elements:

- As $L$ is supposed to be $\mathcal C^1(\Bbb{R}^3;\Bbb{R})$, $D_2L, D_3L$ are bounded on $[0,1]$.
- The derivative of the linear map $f \mapsto f^\prime$ is itself as it is linear and we're using the *appropriate norm*.
- The chain rule.